# How can you run `kubectl -f apply <file.yaml>` from a DAG using bash operator in Cloud Composer?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-composer

Im trying to apply a config file to create a POD from Cloud Compose using the BashOperator

First I tried using the PodOperator but it doesnt allow to pass a spec file, it just builds from the image.

I tried using the BashOperator since the worker already includes gcloud, kubectl, etc. https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/writing-dags#bashoperator

But every time I run a command I get some error with the arguments or with gcloud sdk.

I tried running single kubectl commands and kubectl is indeed installed on the worker.

I tried setting the config for the cluster before but I got errors on that call too.

```py
job = BashOperator(
    task_id='start',
    bash_command='kubectl apply -f
/home/airflow/gcs/dags/.../spec.yaml',
    env=prodigy_env
    )
```

I expect the pod to be created effectively with the config file but the actual output is

`{bash_operator.py:124} INFO - unable to recognize - Path to file`

*If you run a cat /path the file indeed exists

Comment: I am running airflow locally and running kubectl commands will run on my local machine. Can you help how can I run kubectl commands on GCP using bash operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to answer, apparently passing env vars through the bash operator was messing up with the execution.

The path exists and I was able to run the script without any problems I just couldn't pass env variables that way.

I ended up passing them in the `spec.yaml`

Answer (score 0):

You are having issues probably because although you have `gcloud` auth configured you still have to get `kubectl` credentials for the cluster:

```sh
gcloud container clusters get-credentials $CLUSTER_NAME --zone $GCP_ZONE --project $PROJECT_ID
```

Run this command before `kubectl apply -f
/home/airflow/gcs/dags/.../spec.yaml`

Answer (score -1):

The content of DAGs bucket `Buckets/<your bucket>/dags/` is copied to '/home/airflow/gcsfuse/dags/' on workers preserving the folder structure.

If your spec.yaml is stored in your DAGs bucket like this `Buckets/<your bucket>/dags/<subfolder1>/spec.yaml` then the file should be available under the following path `/home/airflow/gcsfuse/dags/<subfolder1>/spec.yaml`.

Just taking a look on the "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/.../spec.yaml'" path from the file system perspective - instead of "..." you probably should use ".." to refer to folder above "dags" folder.

--

On the other hand, there is an alternative to creating a Pod using explicitly invoking `kubectl` command - namely you could use `KubernetesPodOperator` - [this web page describes how to use KubernetesPodOperator to create Pods](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/using-kubernetes-pod-operator)